# How to make a decision to create a new child class

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

What is the best way to handle blank final variables in scenarios where some callers know its value and some do not?

In the below scenario should I be creating a new child class to instantiate c2?

```
class Parent {
    private int p1;
    private int p2;

}

class Child1 extends Parent {
  private final int c1;

  //want to add a final variable c2 here but cannot add since one of the callers do not the know the value of c2;

  public Child1(int c1){
    this.c1 = c1;
  }
}


class Service {

    public  void createChild(int c1){
        Child c1 = new Child1(c1);
        //business logic
    }


}

class ServiceCall1 {

    createChild(10);

    // I do not know the value of c2 here
}

class ServiceCall2 {

    createChild(20);

    //I know the value of c2 here 

}
```

Comment: You could just write a getter/setter for F2 that encodes the final-ness but allows it to be initialized after C1 is instantiated. If you *really* need that kind of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear.
Can you show some code?

But in general, I think class-inherit is driven by the entity's relationship.

For example, a parent class `Person`, it has a child class `Student`. As we all know, Studen is a person, so this structure is a good choice.
Another child class `Teacher`, it should be inherited from `Person`, not `Student`. Because in school, the one who is a student and also a teacher is very very rare.
So if class `Teacher` inherits from `Student`, it's strange and not a good choice.

And I think the `blank final variable` is language-level things.
I suggest don't make class-inherit dependent on those things.